# Current characteristics of ISO7421 isolator IC

Tags: current, safety, isolation

I am using an ISO7421 IC for serial communication isolation. I have read the datasheet of the [ISO7421](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7421.pdf?ts=1625473713219&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). I am not able to understand the current characteristics given in the datasheet.

My concern is if somehow things go wrong and a short circuit occurs on the input side or excessive current through input side of the IC, will this damage the output side of IC?

Is there any practical way of testing this?

I am using a critical component on output side and I want to protect it in any case, so is there any other solution for this? I am open to different solutions as well.

Comment: That seems to be an isolator to isolate from high voltages, not from short circuit. I don't see an `Ics`, `Icn` or `Icu` listed.

Answer (score 6):

> *My concern is if somehow things get wrong due to which short circuit
> occurs on input side or excessive current through input side of the
> IC, will this damage the output side of IC?*

It looks to me that the destruction of the input circuit won't affect the output circuit but, if your "critical component" is especially sensitive, you do need to ensure a couple of things first: -

- The output circuit can only deliver a limited output current to your critical component - this can be achieved via a series resistor in the output usually (simple).
- The output circuit can only deliver a limited output voltage to your critical component - this usually depends on the output circuit power supply voltage being carefully controlled.

But, there's a further concern and that relates to transient immunity between input and output. You have isolated for a reason and, it may be a fairly benign reason such as not wanting to share an earth node with the possibility for external fault currents to flow into your circuit. That's a valid and normal reason.

But, you may have isolated because there is a substantial voltage difference between input and output that may be oscillating at a high frequency. This very often happens in moderate to high-power switch mode controllers.

To service this second scenario, the ISO7421 is designed to operate with the input banging up and down with respect to the output at a slew rate of typically 40,000 volts per μs (table 6.8 in data sheet). It's intended to operate under these situations but, if that is your type of application, you should consider the implications of the isolation barrier capacitance and the surge current it can induce.

That barrier capacitance is typically 1 pF (section 8.3.2) and, if you need to withstand large transients at the input with respect to the output, the 1 pF provides a parasitic path for current injections into the output. You may not have considered this.

For instance with a \$\frac{dv}{dt}\$ of 40,000,000,000 (that's 40 kV per μs) and 1 pF isolation capacitance, the current injected into your output circuit is: -

$$C\dfrac{dv}{dt} = 40\text{ mA}$$

It can manifest like this (modified from figure 8 of the data sheet): -

[image]

Where does the 40 mA go - it might all travel safely to local ground but, more likely a decent proportion is going to reach the output pin and possibly harm anything sensitive that is connected to it. For simple opto-isolators, pretty much all that surge current is going to be forced out of the two output pins. Yes, opto-isolators have an isolation capacitance of circa 1 pF - beware of this.

So, if you have this situation, you need to take special care on the output to ensure that this current is diverted away from your "critical component". This is usually done with capacitance to local ground on the output pins and some form of Zener-clamp. Sometimes, an inductor may be used.

Regarding the operational side of things, if you wish to receive data from the input to the output intact and reliably, you might need to use a differential amplifier so that the nasty spike of 40 mA is handled without corruption.